# Dualizing complex of Cohen-Macaulay variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, derived-functors, cohen-macaulay

I have a question on a proposition from Shihoko Ishii's book "introduction to Singularities":

Preliminaries: A Noetherian local ring $R$ with the maximal ideal $m$ is called *Cohen-Macaulay ring* if $\operatorname{depth} R = \dim R$. An algebraic variety or an analytic space $X$ or a scheme of finite type is called Cohen–Macaulay if for every
$x \in X$, the local ring $O_{X,x}$ is a Cohen–Macaulay ring.

The *dualizing complex* is introduced and is defined in Note 3.5.9 (main source: Hartshorne's "Residues and Duality"; abbrev by Ha1):

> **Note 3.5.9 (dualizing complex [Ha1, V, §2])**. Let $X$ be an algebraic variety, let
>   $\mathcal{C} = (Mod_{O_X} )$ and let $D_c(\mathcal{C} )$ be the subcategory of $D(\mathcal{C})$ (= the derived category of $\mathcal{C}$: see) consisting of complexes
>   with each cohomology coherent. The subcategory $D^+
> _c (\mathcal{C})$ of $D^+
> (\mathcal{C})$ is defined in the same way. An object $R^• \in D^+
> _c (Mod_{O_X} )$ is called a dualizing complex if it has an
>   injective resolution of finite length and for a functor $D = \mathbb{R}Hom( , R^•
> ) : D_c(\mathcal{C})^0 \to
> D_c(\mathcal{C})$ the canonical morphism $\mathcal{F}^• \to DD\mathcal{F}^•$ is isomorphic. A dualizing complex
>   is not unique [Ha1, V, 3.1], but a normalized dualizing complex $D^•
> X$ is locally unique
>   up to isomorphisms in $D^+
> _c (\mathcal{C})$ [Ha1, V, §6].

The proposition states

> **Proposition 3.5.12.** For an $n$-dimensional algebraic variety $X$, the following are
>   equivalent:
>
> (i) X is a Cohen–Macaulay variety;
>
> (ii) $D_{X^{\bullet}} \cong D_X^{-n}[n]$ (i.e., $D_{X^{\bullet}}$
>   is the complex with $D_X^{-n}$
>   as the $−n$-part and with $0$ as
>   the other parts).
>
> In this case $D_X^{-n} \cong \omega_X $, holds, where $\omega_X$ is the canonical sheaf that will be defined in Sect. 5.3.

**Question**: Unfortunately, for this Proposition the book neither gives a proof nor a reference. The main source Hartshorne's "Residues and Duality" not contains such statement. Does anybody know where a proof of this Proposition can be found?

Comment: There is a proof in lemma 20.2 of here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/dualizing.pdf#page31

Comment: @AGlearner: I see. Obviously we can work locally. Say $X= Spec(A)$. 20.2 is refering to Lemma 16.7. What I not understand why is $Ext^i _A(A, D_{X^{\bullet}})= D_{X^{\bullet}}^{-i}[i]$?

Comment: By taking injective resolution $D_X^{\bullet}\to I^{\bullet}$, $Ext_A^i(A,D_X^{\bullet})$ is the $i$-th cohomology of the complex $Hom_A(A,I^{\bullet})=I^{\bullet}$. The theorem says that this complex is supported at degree $i=-d$, so $D_X^{\bullet}$ is quasiisomorphic to $H^{-d}(I^{\bullet})[d]$.

Comment: By the way, I didn't understand the proof of Lemma 16.7 completely: It states "If $M$ is Cohen-Macauley, then only $Ext_A^{-d}(M,\omega_A^{\bullet})$ can be nonzero." Do you know why?